# How to join dic key and values, and print list

Tags: dictionary, join, key

I have a Input dict: fruit_dict = {"a": "Apple", "b": "Banana", "c": "Pear"}

I have this code:

```
new_list = []
new_val = '|'. join(x+'|' + y for x, y in fruit_dict.items())
new_list.append(new_val)
print(new_list)
```

Output I am getting: = ['a|Apple|b|Banana|c|Pear']

Output I am expecting:  = ["a|Apple", "b|Banana", "c|Pear"]

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
new_val = ['|'.join((x, y)) for x, y in fruit_dict.items()]
```

Comment: It is sort of producing the similar result. But adding two square bracket instead of one. Also, it is not adding double quote.

Comment: You should not need two square brackets. it is a list comprehension - returning a single list. when i run it and print new_val I get ` ['a|Apple', 'b|Banana', 'c|Pear']. The single quotes are interchangeable with double quotes as they both just denote the the element enclosed is a string. Or do you specifically want double quotes to also be part of the string that is printed?

Comment: Yes, I understand the quotes are interchangeable. However I specifically need double quote. I tried putting double quote like "|" this but didn't work.

Comment: Do't know if this is what you want: `new_val = ['|'.join(('"'+x, y+'"')) for x, y in fruit_dict.items()]`. It will have the values of your list with double quotes but when you print the list it will have single quotes around those double quotes as well. I'm not sure if you merely want to print the list showing the elements are strings by using double quotes or whether you ctully want double quotes as part of the variables value?